# quesiton about residuals and poles

Tags: complex-analysis

I have got some quesitons about residuals and poles in complex analysis. I have two questions, the first one is very easy, the second one is not so easy I think.

First, we know that if f has a pole of order n at $z_0$, then it can be written as:

$f(z)=\frac{a_{-n}}{(z-z_0)^n}+...+\frac{a_{-1}}{(z-z_0)}+G(z)$

Where G is a holomorphic function in a neighberhood of $z_0$.

Now my questions.

1. Can we have a residual that is 0?I guess another way of asking is if we can integrate around a pole of order n, and get 0?
2. In the book there is an example. They have a function, and they know they have a pole at $z_0$, but they don't know which order the pole is. We know that **IF** we know that the pole has order 1, then:

$$res_{z_0}f=\lim_{z \rightarrow z_0}(z-z_0)f(z)$$

However they didn't know what that the pole had order 1, but they tried to calculate this value, and then found out that it's value was -1, and then they concluded that the pole had order 1.

**Now, if this value had been 0, could they then have claimed that the pole had order 1? What would have to happen to rule out that the pole had order 1?, because when they started they didn't know the order.**

Comment: It's best to ask one well-defined question per post. Doing so will increase the probability that you get an answer.

Comment: @DanielSank Thanks, I'll try to remember that for next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.)  Yes, you can have a pole with residue $0$.  The residue of $f$ at $z_0$ equals the $a_{-1}$ coefficient in the Laurent series expansion of $f$ at $z_0$.  So, for example, $\frac{1}{z^2}$ has a pole at $0$ with residue $0$.

2.)  We know that the pole must've been order 1 because the limit of $(z-z_0)f(z)$ as $z\rightarrow z_0$ exists.  If we consider the Laurent expansion for $f$ at $z_0$, then we see that if $f$ had a pole of higher order, this limit wouldn't exist ($(z-z_0)f(z)$ would still blow up as we walked toward $z_0$).

Comment: Thanks!, but why would it blow up? If you look at the expression I wrote, there are many terms that get big, can't these cancel each other out in some way?

Comment: That's a valid worry, but it turns out not to happen. The last term "blows up the fastest", swamping all other terms. One way to see this is to write $f(z) = (z-z_0)^{-n} \cdot \big\{ (z-z_0)^n f(z) \big\}$; the second factor approaches $a_{-n}$ as $z\to z_0$, while the first factor blows up, so the product $f(z)$ must blow up.